# Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'GenericObject'

Tags: typescript

```
const initialApprovalCounts = approvalStatusStrings.reduce( <GenericObject extends { [k: string]: number }>( finalObject: GenericObject, status: string ) => {
    finalObject[ status ] = 0 // error below
    return finalObject
}, {} )

/*
Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'GenericObject'.ts(2536)
(parameter) finalObject: GenericObject extends { [k: string]: number; }
*/
```

Is not the 2nd line of the error saying strings ARE indexing this object type?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a generic instead of just `finalObject: {[k: string]: number}`?  And note that `{a: number} extends {[k: string]: number}` is true, but the former has no index signature and you cannot index into it with an arbitrary `string`.  The existence of [implicit index signatures](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures) does weird things here.  See [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NDzzlW).  If you want, I could write that up as an answer... but if you still have outstanding questions or issues, please elaborate.

Comment: This solved it, thanks! I was trying a bunch of stuff and the generic type was no longer needed as you pointed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking to see if an object type is assignable to another type with an [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), the compiler will sometimes give the object type an [*implicit* index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures).  As long as all the known properties of the object type* are assignable to the index signature, the assignment will succeed:

For example:

```
type Foo = { a: number };
type Bar = { [k: string]: number };

type Extends<T, U extends T> = void;
type FooExtendsBar = Extends<Bar, Foo>; //okay
```

You can see that the compiler believes that `Foo extends Bar`. For the purposes of the check, it treats `Foo` *as if* it had an index signature of type `number`, and so `Foo` is assignable to `Bar`.

---

But such implicit index signatures only exist during such a check. Object types without explicit index signature will not let you index into them with a key of type `string` or for any string literal index that isn't a known key:

```
type Okay = Bar[string]; // okay
type Oops = Foo[string]; // error, Type 'Foo' has no matching index 
                         // signature for type 'string'.

type AlsoOkay = Bar["abcde"]; // okay
type AlsoOops = Foo["abcde"]; // Property 'abcde' does not exist on type 'Foo';
```

---

And so *that* means it is possible for a generic `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `{[k: string]: number}` to fail to have a string index signature:

```
approvalStatusStrings.reduce(<T extends { [k: string]: number }>(
    finalObject: T, status: string) => {
    finalObject[status] = 0 // <-- error, Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'
    return finalObject
}, {})
```

The compiler is saying that, for all it knows, `T` will be `Foo` (`{a: number}`), while `status` is some general `string` value like `"abcde"`, and `Foo["abcde"]` is an error.  So it won't let you write `finalObject[status]` without complaint.

---

In this particular example, the generic type parameter doesn't seem to buy you anything. You can just declare the type of `finalObject` to be the specific type that has an index signature:

```
const initialApprovalCounts = approvalStatusStrings.reduce((
    finalObject: { [k: string]: number }, status: string) => {
    finalObject[status] = 0 // okay
    return finalObject
}, {})
```

and the error goes away.  That's what I'd suggest here. Obviously there will be some use cases where you don't have the luxury of dispensing with the generic type parameter, and so in those situations you would either rephrase the generic constraint so that `status` is definitely a known key of `finalObject`:

```
<K extends string>(
    finalObject: Record<K, number>, status: K) => {
    finalObject[status] = 0 // okay
    return finalObject
}
```

or, if things get really hairy, just triple check that your implementation is good and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error:

```
<T extends { [k: string]: number }>(
    finalObject: T, status: string) => {
    (finalObject as Record<string, number>)[status] = 0 // okay
    return finalObject
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgewTAvDA3jAhgLhgOwFcBbAIygCcYBfAblElgCEsq1MBtAazwGcQKAS3wBzALp4iZSjXoNoMAKIAPEFHwATXgB4AKgBoYAVRhRV6rTF0A+VDABuCQRrngFiBCrWbeLNkvMfbT9DD2taGAB6SIQuLDBgYGE1CgAzLABjWA8ASXwU9KyMbEkScio6eWykPILMqC8LX1Y7RqCQ+Br8ykKocKjI0woKBApDYl5I3QBlAGIARgBWAGYABlXEt1gAeTiwOz8OfiFRMQjomFj4qphthAheOw8jgWFxc8HKEbGrRhgAcg8-xgAAssI98MhiFgQBkQW8YMINGYYLxBCJ8DDCBRYKlRjAtgDjm9-gA6TZ-ACCABteAhdvEDqwOAAiLCkDLIllnAaXPY3Gl0u4PJ5IVnszlQbkfGAABRG0Ao4ABEuRwI0CCgEIQIFMykE-Eu+AJf0BSH+ckSyIy1NYsAyCHwhqwEAgI3sWGp0xAWN43pOIl4fFeog4YkSiQdTt1wkEIEEnsprvdnoAwghCPleMLHmgXW6EB6vT6QIQ-SHA6ScRpCFkABR6PXeSycHioisSAhlGTUax14AwQcwVLCT3bUgAKygGRAeAM7d9wYDAEpULZ0AOhyPMdTx1OZy9fWI7KtedoALTnobfQy6U3E0TAjJYfCQ3XkGBlqAaAnIJEowl-l0f5N0HHFSwoY1tzHSdpxAYBqEMdBqGXSNHUNWN40TZNCzTDMszsfMU2LX1-TeXgq2-WsoDrfsh2HUdd1gmc8FbJc3k7KRyhoQx+EXdsVzXDBQIYnc9zgw9S14Y80FPC4rgSejwOxKDGPEmcEKQlCI2AKNDRBYhiEInCi29UiKwo6tqIbABpJsmgEt4+xE6CmP3WcYAAJWnUYNG0GzDC4yhrF4ksyzwGzVxQdcXLU5iQEkssZJgOTBgUkTlMg0SYPczSMGobBHm8h0KD8h8REC7sKGsVDdPQ3VwV4SgQG2bEAHV4la3U8xMz0zKksjREsqj60bMxm0eNjHNOUppAqZz6Nc9SPPnPipPY0Qopi+i6yW+LCq8nzSu0crKrmmrEukk9eXSpSoAg1SxPivLkNqnSgA)

<sub>*this only works for anonymous object literal types like `{a: string}` or type aliases of such anonymous types like `type Foo = {a: string}`.  Object types declared as `interface`s or a `class`es do *not* get implicit index signatures; see [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)</sub>